# Unable to resolve unmet dependency problem with apt - pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, apt

It has been days which I tried installing MongoDB and I had dependencies problem. `apt --fix-broken install` couldn't solve my problem. I can use `sudo apt-get update` because of this broken dependencies

I searched for solutions online and everywhere I keep seeing use
`sudo apt-get clean`
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
`sudo apt autoremove --purge`
`sudo apt-get autoclean --dry-run`
`sudo apt-get purge mongodb*`
`sudo dpkg --audit` and many more. None of them solved my problem.

I am not able to install any new package, these broken dependencies keep preventing me from doing so.

here is the specific error in the console

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing more research, I was able to remove the packages with broken dependencies using

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <Package-name>`

Which in my case was `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org`, And it worked.

Comment: Before installing any packages with dpkg, Make sure you run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` as root